# With php check how long a file has been inside a directory (unix)?

Tags: php, unix

Is it possible to check how long a file has been inside a directory?

Background: I have a script that moves a file inside a new processing directory. I want to check how long it has been in this directory. If it has been for more than 2 hours then the processing script has probably timed out. So I want to move it outside the directory and run the script again.

`filemtime()` returns only the last edit time

Thanks!

Comment: Save yourself some future headache and use a simple queue system instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filectime(), see php manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php

> Returns the time the file was last changed, or FALSE on failure. The time is returned as a Unix timestamp.

You may want to write you own utility function:

```
function fileOlderThanHours($filename, $hours = 2) {
    $ctime = filectime($filename);
    return (time() - $ctime) > ($hours * 60 * 60);
}
```